# Jboss EAP 7.1.6 failover not working when have two nodes in cluster

Tags: java, wildfly, failover, jboss-eap-7

I was investigating an issue related to the failover test when it only has two nodes. Here is the scenario.

**Test steps:**

1. We have two node cluster, let’s take them as node1 and node2.
2. Initially, node1 is up and running, but node2 Is down and the client is connected to the node1.
3. Once the node2 is fully started, we have stopped node1.
4. In this scenario, the client got freeze and log out the user from the system.

**Investigation steps:**

1. When node2 starting, before it is fully started (partially started), node discovery was marked node2 as failed destination and put it into the cache object.
2. Even node2 fully started it is not removing from the cache.
3. When node1 stopped, it also marked as the failed destination. In this situation, both nodes marked as failed from the discovery.
4. Even the second pass happens, this failed destination cache is not clearing. But when I clear the cache as below. Discovery was successful.

```
        if (discoveryConnections && ! ok) {
            if (failedDestinations != null)
            {
                failedDestinations.clear();
            }
            Logs.INVOCATION.tracef("EJB discovery provider: all connections marked failed, retrying ...");
            for (EJBClientConnection connection : configuredConnections) {
                if (! connection.isForDiscovery()) {
                    continue;
                }
                URI destination = connection.getDestination();
                Logs.INVOCATION.tracef("EJB discovery provider: attempting to connect to connection %s", destination);
                discoveryAttempt.connectAndDiscover(destination, null);
            }
        }
```

But to happen proper failover, when a node is up and running, it should be clear from the JBoss failddestination cache object.

This is giving both nodes as failed and cached, it is not cleared when servers are up

Comment: Any suggestions, please?